# Applications of the property of transcendence

Tags: transcendental-numbers

I was learning the proofs of the transcendence of $e$ and $\pi$, and I was wondering what would be the usefulness of these results.

So my questions are:

- Are there any (relatively simple) application of the transcendence of $e$?
- More generally, why is it useful to know that a number $x$ is transcendent?

*When I talk about transcendence here, I am putting myself in the simplest case: a real number $x$ being transcendent over $\mathbb Q$.*

Comment: Transcendence of $\pi$ shows that squaring the circle is not possible :-)

Comment: @Watson Nice application! It only requires that $\pi$ is not algebraic of degree $2^n$ if I recall correctly. Great use of the transcendence though :)